# Can't see logical issue on this simple program

Tags: c

I wrote this program, and it was supposed to read the numbers, calculate the medium value and print the closest number to it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    const int num = 6;

    int i, i2 = num - 1;
    float numeros[num], dist[num];
    float media = 0;

    for (i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("Digite um numero\n");
        scanf("%f", &numeros[i]);
        media = media + numeros[i];
    }
    media = media / num;
    for (i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if (numeros[i] <= media){
            dist[i] = media - numeros[i];
        }
        else{
            dist[i] = numeros[i] - media;
        }
    }
    for (i = num - 2; i >= 0; i--){
        if (dist[i] < dist[i + 1]){
        i2 = i;
        }
    }
    printf("O numero mais proximo da media '%1.0f' eh '%1.0f'", media, numeros[i2]);

    printf("\n\nPressione 'Enter' para sair");
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
return 0;
}
```

But sometimes i get something like

> input 50 50 50 500 24 20 (ok)
>
> media 116 (ok)
>
> prints 24 (?)

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

Comment: You're not checking the return value from `scanf()`.

Comment: `Int main()` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: That will not even compile. What is `Int`?

Comment: @cad what do you mean by undefined behavior? I used it so the program can stop after it prints the result (as I saw somewhere else here). If I remove it the program just quits and I can't read the result.

Comment: See the standard: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2p2 No further discussion necessary.

Comment: @DaviRibeiro Use terminal software (for example "command prompt" on windows) to see result.

Comment: Try googling it. Also what undefined behavior is. It is undefined by the standard, that's all it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `Int main()` should be `int main(void)`
- Do not use `fflush(stdin)`, which is undefined behavior.
- The condition `dist[i] < dist[i + 1]` is wrong. It should be `dist[i] < dist[i2]` because the index of the best element should be stored in `i2` and the element should be compared to other elements.